# Why can Kotlin high order functions have named arguments?

Tags: kotlin

Let's take the following code snippet:

```
class Foo {
    fun bar(baz: (x: String) -> Unit) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It compiles correctly both in that way and with `baz: (String) -> Unit` (note that `x:` has been removed here)

Why is it possible to name the first argument of `baz` function as `x`? Can it be used in any way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is optional to provide extra meaning for callers of the `bar` method, to let them know what the the `baz` method they're passing in will receive as their parameter.

It will show up in IntelliJ when looking up the `bar` method's documentation with `Ctrl + Q`, and it will autocomplete `x ->` if you hit `Ctrl + Space` inside the lambda passed to `bar` as well. Of course callers can still name the incoming parameter of the lambda however they'd like, but this can be useful especially if the lambda has multiple parameters.

For example, with this higher order function:

```
fun bar(foo: (foo1: Int, foo2: Int, foo3: Int) -> Unit) {
    // ...
}
```

IDEA will automatically give you this lambda body when you choose the `bar` function from autocompletion:

```
bar { foo1, foo2, foo3 ->

}
```

Comment: The [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types) mentions your first point about documenting, so the second point you make about IDE assistance is pretty interesting.