# Kotlin: what does annotation (acc: S, T) -> S mean?

Tags: kotlin

I'm very new to Kotlin. I looked at Kotlin's source code and I saw this prototype:

```
public inline fun <S, T : S> Iterable<T>.reduce(operation: (acc: S, T) -> S): S
```

I understand that operation is a method, 'acc' is one its arguments, 'acc' is of type S and the return value of operation is of type S. However, what does the T inside list of arguments mean?
Where is its arguments?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can Kotlin high order functions have named arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48834273/why-can-kotlin-high-order-functions-have-named-arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naming the function parameters in a function type is optional. The names are only significant for documentation purposes.

What the above says is that `reduce` expects a function taking an `S` (the accumulated value) and a `T` (the current element). They gave the `S` the name `acc`, but didn't give the `T` any name.

Answer (score 1):

`(acc: S, T) -> S` is a type.

In Kotlin, [functions are first-class types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types).  Some types have a simple name, such as `String` or `Int`.  Others need parameters, such as `List<URL>` or `Map<Int, String>`.  Function types have even more complicated names, of the form:

`(`*params*`) ->` *returnType*

So a function which takes a single `Int` parameter and returns a `String` would have the type `(Int) -> String`.

You can also give names to the parameters if you want, e.g. `(count: Int) -> String`, though the name is ignored.

So in your example, the `reduce()` method takes a single parameter, called `operation`.  That parameter is a function which itself takes two parameters (the first called `acc` of type `S`, and the second of type `T` with no name), and returns a value of type `S`.

What's particular confusing in your case is that `S` and `T` are type parameters: they refer to types that aren't known yet.  When the `reduce()` method is called, the caller will specify them (or the compiler will infer them).  That's what the `<S, T : S>` after the `fun` means: the method needs two type parameters: `S`, and `T` (which must be `S` or a subtype).